# Local node communication between local nodes in Point-to-Site VPN in Azure

Tags: azure, vpn

If we create a point-to-site VPN on azure, would communications between two nodes on a LAN, connected to the VPN and using VPN Front-end IPs, happen through Azure Gateway or directly through the LAN?

Answer (score 0):

The communication paths depend on the source and destination IP addresses. When you connect to Azure P2S, just like most other VPN technology, P2S VPN assigns a virtual IP address for the tunnel interface (say 192.168.0.x), while the machines will have physical IP addresses (say 10.0.0.x). If you send packets using 10.x addresses, it should traverse directly over the LAN. If you send packets using the 192.x addresses, then it will go over the P2S tunnels and Azure gateway.

Thanks,
Yushun [MSFT]